# Iterate over nested arrays in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

At my backend I send a `data.ent` JSON which has a nested arrays as pic shows:

[image]

How do I iterate over this result? I've tried with:

```
$.each(data.ent, function (index, value) { 
    console.log(value.modeloMarcaProducto);
}
```

But get `undefined`, I think I am missing something here but what? Which is the right way to iterate trhough `data.ent`? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an array where each element in the array is itself an array of objects.  If that's what you have, then you have to iterate both levels of arrays, both the top level array and then each nested array and that inner iteration will get you each object from the inner array which you can then reference your property on like this:

```
$.each(data.ent, function (index, value) { 
    $.each(value, function (i, v) {
        console.log(v.modeloMarcaProducto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your callback, `value` is an array of objects (it seems to always include one array with only include one object though) so you can just reference `value[0][0]`.

```
$.each(data.ent, function (index, value) { 
 console.log(value[0][0].modeloMarcaProducto);
}
```

Alternatively, you would have to recurse

```
var vals = [];
(function recurseKeyValue( obj, key ){
 for( all in obj )
 {
    if( all == key ){
     console.log(obj[all]);
     vals.push(obj[all]);
     continue;
    }
    if( typeof obj[all] == "object" && obj[all]!= null ){
        recurseKeyValue( obj[all], key );
    }
 }
})(data.ent,modeloMarcaProducto)
```

Comment: I've change the pic since will be more items in the array so it can't be attached to `value[0]`, any other way? `index`?

Comment: @ReynierPM -You have an array of arrays of objects inside of data.ent. So when you iterate using `each` you will be iterating an array of objects. It would seem each of these arrays of objects only holds one object.